# Vue JS delete objects in array by unique id?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js to remove an object in my object array, problem is I can't find a way to delete the object by it's unique id. I'm using vue.js version 1. I also need  a way to update that same object (it has to be reactive, so my view gets updated automatically).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Vue Js - components</title>
</head>
<body>


<!-- index.html -->
<div id="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <post v-for="posty in posts" :posty="posty" track-by="uuid"></post>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="my-component">
 <div v-if="posty.votes === '15'">
   <button v-on:click="testFunc(posty.uuid)">{{posty.title}}</button>
 </div>
 <div v-else>
   <button v-on:click="testFunc(posty.uuid)">No</button>
 </div>
</template>



<script src="vue-v1.js"></script>
<script>
Vue.component('post', {
  template: "#my-component",
  props: ['posty'],
  methods: {
   testFunc: function(index){
     this.$parent.parentMethod(index);
   }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [{ uuid: '88f86fe9d',
    title: "hello",
    votes: '15'
   },
   { 
    uuid: '88f8ff69d',
    title: "hello",
    votes: '15'
   },
   { 
    uuid: '88fwf869d',
    title: "hello",
    votes: '10'
   }]
  },

  methods: {
   parentMethod: function(index){
    Vue.delete(this.posts, index);
   }
  }
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/fafohinaje/edit?html,js,console,output

I don't know what should your Vue.delete method represent here, so instead you can go with array splice

```
methods: {
  parentMethod: function(index){
    this.posts.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```